# Kernel vs ROOTFS

Tags: linux-kernel

I think I know but I am a bit confused.

Can someone please explain the difference between Kernel and rootfs in embedded system environment?

Comment: The kernel is RAM-resident executable code.  The rootfs is the essential filesystem for the system (initially a ramfs or tmpfs) , but more often is used to refer to a collection of files in a filesystem of some type (e.g. ramfs, ext2/3/4, jffs2, ubifs) that consist of essential initialization and userspace programs.  Both are needed to boot a Linux system.

Answer (score 3):

rootfs is just [an ununmountable ramfs/tmpfs](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt). The kernel is a chunk of code that lives on a real filesystem.

Comment: Your first sentence implies that the rootfs has to be memory resident. That's false.

Comment: @sawdust: ["Rootfs is a special instance of ramfs (or tmpfs, if that's enabled) ..."](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt) You can pivot another root filesystem over it, but the entity called "rootfs" *is* a memory-resident filesystem.

Comment: But the most common and widespread use of *"rootfs"* (e.g. build a rootfs or install a rootfs in NAND) refers to contents of an essential filesystem, rather than that special instance.  The kernel command-line parameter "root=" for specifying the *"root filesystem"* helps perpetuate this (mis)use.

Comment: *"The kernel is a chunk of code that lives on a real filesystem."* -- There is no requirement that the kernel be stored in a filesystem.  The most widely used embedded boot program, U-Boot, can access raw flash.  The convention for Atmel ARM is to store the Linux kernel in raw flash:  http://www.at91.com/linux4sam/bin/view/Linux4SAM/Sama5d3xekMainPage#NandFlash_demo_Memory_map  IIRC Allwinner may also be similar.

Answer (score 1):

rootfs is a not-unmountable ramfs. (Not tmpfs.)
The kernel is a chunk of code that can initially live whereever you want, your bootloader may load it over network, and then into memory. A filesystem may not actually be involved.